# Getting stockmap error after updating spockframework 1.1

Tags: java, grails, spock

I wanted to updated spockframework from 1.0 to 1.1, because of this fix https://github.com/spockframework/spock/pull/100

The application runs on:
Grails 2.4.5
Java 7

I do not have the permission to upgrade grails version and java. Does any one know a nice workaround?

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 56
Exception Details:
  Location:
    grails/test/spock/IntegrationSpec.initTransaction()Lorg/codehaus/groovy/grails/test/support/GrailsTestTransactionInterceptor; @42: ifeq
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0000000: b800 3d4c 2b12 9932 1257 2b12 9a32 2ab9
    0000010: 0074 0200 b900 9d03 004d 2c57 2b12 9e32
    0000020: 2c2a b900 7803 00b8 0055 9900 0e2b 129f
    0000030: 322c b900 a102 0057 2c12 57b8 005d c000
    0000040: 57b0 01b0
```

Comment: I guess that the jvm parameter -XX:-UseSplitVerifier will do the job? But can a set it only doing test run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the  issue by adding useSplitVerifier in BuildConfig.groovy file.

So the build config file look like this:

```
grails.project.fork = [
test       : [... useSplitVerifier: true ...],
]
...
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
...
    dependencies {
        ...
        test ("org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.3")
        ...
    }
...
}
```